# generating report with birt

Tags: mysql, birt, eclipse-pdt

im using birt report designer plugin in eclipse pdt. i successfully built the datasource and data set from mysql database. but when i try to use the data column in my report it generates error with
 error message 
"An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
org/mozilla/javascript/ScriptOrFnNode". 
 i have already built many reports in same configuration without any such problem. but now its not working  what may be the reasons behind this?
 i have tried many suggestions like birt updating, from this as well as some other forums without any improvement 
Thanks..

Comment: Assuming the previous reports you built with the same approach are still working, I suspect you added something to the report and later removed it leaving an artifact in the XML.  Rebuild the report from scratch, testing it as you go, you will either discover the issue, or create the report without the error.

Comment: @JamesJenkins thanks for the suggestion. actually there was no such deleted fields or something. i solved the problem by reinstalling birt plugins in new eclipse. i want to ask one question:can such errors may arise due to incomplete update, i mean plugin not completely updated due to network error! if not what may be other reasons?